# Caller does not have permission error when using GMail API

Tags: django, google-app-engine, gmail-api

I get 500 server error on my django website thats running on Google App Engine. When I look at Google App Engine logs I see the following error:

`googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 403 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/gmail/v1/rest returned "The caller does not have permission">`

When I hard refresh the browser this error goes away. Then after some time it pops back up. Happens on mobile(firefox, safari), laptop (firefox,chrome).

**UPDATE:**

In Django settings.py I have following code. Its last line generates the error :

```
pickle_path = 'token.pickle'  # path to token.pickle
with open(pickle_path, 'rb') as token:
    creds = pickle.load(token)
SERVICE = build('gmail', 'v1', credentials=creds)  # ERROR LINE
```

When I run the django server locally: I get following error:

```
googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 403 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/gmail/v1/rest returned "The caller does not have permission">
```

When I restart cloud sql connection from my terminal - the error is gone. This never used to happen until a few days ago.

Comment: The question should be updated to include desired behavior, a specific problem or error, and the shortest code necessary to reproduce the problem.

Comment: I too just recently started experiencing this, and only today. Hoping to find an answer soon!

Comment: I thought it was just us, we got an uptick mid last week in failing calls to `build_service('gmail', 'v1', credentials=creds)` in our code. Maybe google changed something.

Comment: We started having this issue today too, does seem to be an issue with Google: `googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 403 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/gmail/v1/rest returned "The caller does not have permission">`

Comment: We're also having this issue as of today. It is most likely a system-wide issue.

Comment: I just tested the python quickstart code from https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/python and it has the same stack trace with `<HttpError 403 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/gmail/v1/rest returned "The caller does not have permission">` - I sent feedback on that page that the example code does not work

Comment: Seems like google fixed this. They also fixed another issue - previously when a MP4 video was uploaded to cloud storage, a GET url would not play well (only audio was played, no video ) on laptop browsers. Now it works

Answer (score 3):

Here's a workaround:

- Download the discovery_doc directly from google [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/googleapis/google-api-go-client/master/gmail/v1/gmail-api.json)
- Load the json file (you can name it `gmail-api.json`)
- Build from this json file using `build_from_document`

**Before**

```py
    from googleapiclient.discovery import build

    gmail_creds = get_service_account_creds()
    gmail_service = build('gmail', 'v1', credentials=gmail_creds)
```

**After**

```py
    from googleapiclient.discovery import build_from_document

    discovery_doc = load_json('config/gmail-api.json')
    gmail_creds = get_service_account_creds()

    gmail_service = build_from_document(discovery_doc, credentials=gmail_creds)
```

---

It seems that it is now a P0 for Google, so hopefully it will be fixed soon.

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/160441983

Answer (score 1):

I am also started facing this issue. I have been using Google APIs for more than a year, but suddenly this error `HttpError 403 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/gmail/v1/rest returned "The caller does not have permission`. However, couple of times I didn't see this error and API call was successful. I hope this error at the Gmail API server.

Update:
I am able to call Google APIs without any issues. Seems like issue is resolved at google's end.

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same issue with GAM ADV-X. I thought it was an issue on my computer so I tried on 2 different computers and get the same error. It indeed looks like something changed in the Gmail API over the weekend. Will submit a ticket to Google.

Comment: Google is aware. I have submitted a support ticket.